# Insert characters into string in different locations

Tags: string, excel, text, worksheet-function, vba

I have a string which looks like this `20141007023617`. And I would like to make it look like this `2014-10-07T02:36:17Z`. The `T` and `Z` are very important for me. So I would like to insert them as well.

So a recap,

`A1` holds this string          `20141007023617`

`B1` should hold this string    `2014-10-07T02:36:17Z`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try, Record Macro and:

```
=LEFT(A1,4)&"-"&MID(A1,5,2)&"-"&MID(A1,7,2)&"T"&MID(A1,9,2)&":"&MID(A1,11,2)&":"&MID(A1,13,2)&"Z"
```

Answer (score 10):

Solution with `TEXT` function:

```
=TEXT(A1,"0000-00-00\T00\:00\:00\Z")
```

Comment: A really clean and easy solution!

Comment: The question specifies "A1 holds string", not a number.  Your solution returns #VALUE error.  TEXT() represents a numeric value as a (formatted) string.

Comment: @AlanK `TEXT` works fine if the number is stored as string (text). If you are getting `#VALUE` then maybe you have some other characters in text preventing conversion to number (eg invisible like CR, LF)

Comment: @BrakNicku Right you are!  Although the question does not specify that input is a number (or purely numeric string - implicitly of correct length), your answer hits the example spot-on.  Up-vote for teaching me something.

Answer (score 2):

On top of that if you would like to do it with VBA you can use following code. Whenever you run this code it will write the result to the next column same row.

```
Sub arranges()
Dim str As String


str = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Left(str, 4) & "-" & Mid(str, 5, 2) & "-" & Mid(str, 7, 2) _
                                & "T" & Mid(str, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(str, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(str, 13, 2) & "Z"

End Sub
```